# Removing beginning and end character from String without altering array

Tags: php, arrays, substr

I'm running a query to display an array. After the array is displayed I'm using that in Google Maps so the array needs to read a specific way.

```
var addresses = ['Norway', 'Africa', 'Asia','North America','South America'];
```

So my array has to read array', 'array', 'array because I echo the array into the address.

```
var addresses = ['<?php echo $namelist ?>'];
```

This is my code and it outputs 'array', 'array', 'array',

```
$resultsearch = $con->query("SELECT * FROM db") or die(mysqli_error());
$name = array();
while ($result = $resultsearch->fetch_object()) {
$name[] = $result->name;
$namelist = substr("'".implode($name)."', ", 0, -1);
```

If I change the 0, -1 to 1, -2 then I'm left with array' array' array' and so forth.

I literally need the remove 1 character from the end of string and 1 character at the beginning without altering the characters of the array.

Just to add that using `implode(',', $name);` did not display the **','** which is why I'm trying to find a work around.

Any ideas?

Comment: Tip: If you use `implode()` you dont need `substr()` to remove trailling comma!

Comment: Just use implode("','", $name); without your `substr` function ;-)

Comment: `implode($name)` Wrong parameter count! Did you copy paste your code wrong? Else the code will not work. implode takes GLUE as first parameter  http://php.net/results.php/?q=implode

Comment: `implode(",", $name);` does not do anything... that's why I removed the glue and just tried to alter the output with `substr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with `$namelist = "'".$result->name."',"` and then `echo $namelist;`

My results were addresses and believe that `implode(',', $name)` wouldn't work because of the results.

Answer (score 0):

Your problems are:

- You use `implode();` in the wrong way: right is `implode("', '",$names);`
- `substr()` will not work because of wrong use of `implode()`.

Tip: Instead of using `substr()` just do `rtrim('value',',');`

To fix your code change it to this:

```
 $name[] = "'{$result->name}'";
 $namelist = implode(', ',$name);
```

or this

```
 $name[] = $result->name;
 $namelist = implode("', '",$name);
```

And this too:

```
var addresses = [<?php echo $namelist ?>];
```

to get proper javascript/json array data.

Also works: 
`var addresses = <?php echo json_encode($namelist); ?>;`

But here you should not add `'` single-quotes to the names when collecting into an array.

Have a nice day